# getting no response from a url?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests, urllib

Getting no response from a `url` by using `requests.get` on the other hand if I past the url in Firefox then it's responding. The provided `url` is a link of a json file. I don't know what's happening? here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
import requests
import pprint
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=ACC"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)

##data_json = json.loads(response.read())
df = pd.read_json(response)
pprint.pprint(df['records'][1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This website protects itself from bots. There are so many ways to detect bots, some of them are:

- requests rate
- disabled javascript
- empty cookies
- not using mouse to click buttons
- etc.

To enable javascript and cookies, you can use `selenium`.

The website you want to scrape has powerful bot detection methods. I couldn't access the link that you have shared. But when I first tried website main page and after that your link, It shows json file.
But this is not easy to make a bot for. I tried selenium and clicked the website button by moving the mouse, but it detected that I'm a bot. So we can conclude that the website uses cookies. You need to generate fake cookies to access the webpage.

Comment: Firefox inspector showing 4 types of cookies i.e response cookie, request cookie,set cookie and cookie so which cookie is important?? and how to do it any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know very much about cookies, but I guess it depends on their bot detection code. Another important thing about cookies, is that they have expiration, and it's not that easy to copy your own cookies to your bot and your bot bypasses their bot-detector.