# 403 Forbidden response in parsing with Python/requests

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests

Despite of using all headers and session, I still have 403 response.
URL itself is correct and can be easily opened in browser.
Here is my code:

```
params = {'path': '/en/categories/capacitors/fixed-capacitors/capacitor-ceramic-multilayer'}
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', \
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7', \
'authority': 'www.arrow.com', 'path': '/en/categories/capacitors/fixed-capacitors/capacitor-ceramic-multilayer?page=1', 'scheme':'https', 'method': 'GET', \
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'cache-control': 'max-age=0', \
'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"',  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0', 'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"', 'sec-fetch-dest': 'document', \
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate', 'sec-fetch-site': 'none', 'sec-fetch-user': '?1', 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1', \
'cookie': 'arrowcurrency=isocode=USD&culture=en-US; website#lang=en; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1681733496593r0.6674114769622976; _gcl_au=1.1.569202029.1681733497; _rdt_uuid=1681733497045.6f8563fc-2666-4243-99e1-d00a1e6a3d4c; _ga=GA1.2.1182715153.1681733497; _mibhv=anon-1681733497285-7461678829_7368; __qca=P0-885743722-1681733497201; acceptedCookiePolicy2=true; _hjSessionUser_1995675=eyJpZCI6IjZjNWYzZjliLWRiMTAtNTBkOC1iOWFkLWIyMDEyMjAwYWQwYyIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2ODE3MzM0OTc1NzgsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _fbp=fb.1.1681814085150.39054842; cookielawinfo-checkbox-necessary=yes; cookielawinfo-checkbox-functional=no; cookielawinfo-checkbox-performance=no; cookielawinfo-checkbox-analytics=no; cookielawinfo-checkbox-advertisement=no; cookielawinfo-checkbox-others=no; ASP.NET_SessionId=utqhvhzknvdhwxaqehenrjsj; bm_sz=E489A6AA48159EF536BE15A42D1C1C36~YAAQl2ReaMi+g6CHAQAAOY3QshOQajlAkk3emy+ZBvHlAe4nW8IDccNQEv6b6UpLDdf+GEgtiKqKGQg6WYHm55kaKtgjqNcGLhbwizqK3EyoCl1TKceKOFOCTwOYcuc2rc/HTbCL/vWeYuyRi0i23mxscbNkNYA7t2dUIJ6NTfot+7o8hGpAaMshmCZ9cQqq4MqJ5UOFy7VVxMEafF6xfQBbyJfArbuX4SRREXQJoeIvXjq1ckir4TcCmGCL/4G7KHYvue/SAZYZcM9W2Bt3wLgZRxAmm6OlREVhpIJpo0Qf0A==~4599863~3224370; gaVisitorType=returning; _gid=GA1.2.2013360223.1682332228; RedirectFromLogin=0; ak_bmsc=97496E1AB864C8474817DE94ED724470~000000000000000000000000000000~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; _hjSession_1995675=eyJpZCI6ImQwODNmN2RlLTk5M2MtNGUxNC04Y2QwLTJjYzJlMDAyOGM0NiIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2ODIzMzIyMjkwNDYsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; IsNewUser=False; ln_or=eyIzNzAwODkwLDQ3MTgyOCI6ImQiLCIzNzAwODkwLDQ3MDU3MzIsNDcxODI4IjoiZCJ9; _br_uid_2=uid=5323906050966:v=13.0:ts=1681733496996:hc=80; utag_main=v_id:01878f20b0c5002239ea2b3d4b240506f001606700978$_sn:4$_se:9$_ss:0$_st:1682337997660$ses_id:1682332228158;exp-session$_pn:7;exp-session; pageviewCount=7; wcs_bt=s_116daf35dfcd:1682336197; _uetsid=083d8960e28b11ed9531536d482e840f; _uetvid=00980d20dd1911edbc12b7026e33ac5a; bm_sv=57ABD03AEC5FA25FDF15B1504260231A~YAAQJWReaLMjnqCHAQAAASQNsxOwpfrdJD+p8E5KoeB8fFc/GMM27w1WwYTGjWvrL009S4CY9Gjc1036D5aGk7ITzAHUx6bcHtztkYOVP6/tmoELt68WSorEJPgF4Ezi1zMVdFJoRuux/B0uxzSYzFX1KlQ1XbisbzX/XFyxCi5LWXZ0W9YLxS7/Zpe1LacxZ3FdE4p7TR03zmryn05Whj6ye9BUj2Q/ZGrifg8czO9TKUHoEkqNKg1W9zX8Ko2n~1; _abck=4EE19D4EFA1645C30D5338DD4304804C~0~YAAQJWReaMUjnqCHAQAA7CkNswnPRj6CZr6XELOGWqjJpRk1snsCfHMoFxgu5rbEyLzww1RU2fRR32dznYA7faobHSPVXfDhR3Ak5xknii2Q0Xo49jeyClqHeQ579qSpnXUTaAoZy/dujiuwUp/9xhjWPRWItAbldE2iD/F2sM8hb7LUPEz+i9B7/YIzoHQ4BGqpyOxyTKSVtu8vaqBzZBlN7HtM+zfss0YbGXzbJlaIkrN/L5EPRKTjpSrsELK2rP6tEtGVbiLKFdCwVmT33YF0idfG1SQTAvKv8LbYiFDxwyqXvVj4YNusxUaRxS4azUVWc4Oro75RzryZVLbxwsDocmkMw9Mje+IS/wFxr3YUHAN2nr8AtosjBEnnM1W+EiNdQT/VPzxPK6tQlsztYsxeaHcfbgc=~-1~-1~-1; RT="z=1&dm=arrow.com&si=bee09bec-cf1c-48cb-bd0f-4c5115935c80&ss=lgup65yu&sl=2c&tt=1wm8&bcn=//684dd328.akstat.io/&obo=1&ld=43rgl&ul=43sne"'}
session = requests.Session()

for i in range(1, 401):
 
  URL = 'https://www.arrow.com/en/categories/capacitors/fixed-capacitors/capacitor-ceramic-multilayer?page={}'.format(i)
  req = session.get(URL, params=params, headers=headers)
  time.sleep(0.25)
  print(URL)
  print(req.status_code)
  break
```

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987542/getting-no-response-from-a-url/68988738#68988738) may help

Comment: Yes, I know. This is the next  I will try, if no idea from community. Honestly speaking, I don`t like to work with Selenuim because of many bugs.

Comment: yeah unfortunately Selenium has lots of bugs. I can give you some advises in case you chose Selenium. Don't use `headless mode`. Don't use Selenium built-in timer. And try to use `find_by_xpath` or `find_by_id` most of the times, `find_by_class` is buggy.

Comment: According my previous experience, Selenium can be normally used only locally via Anaconda or any othe local solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

I could get html by using Selenium together with selenium_stealth and execute_cdp_cmd method.
key components are below:

```
stealth(driver=driver,
        user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                   'Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36',
        languages=["ru-RU", "ru"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        run_on_insecure_origins=True,
        )
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    'source': '''
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol;
  '''
})
```

This is also impossible here to combine Selenium and BeatifullSoup, because bs cannot normally read markup, returned by webdriver.

Comment: you can use selenium-wire https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/ where you can alter and inject headers because you use your own self-signed client certificate in browser. 
but arrow also has a rest-api (although not free): https://developers.arrow.com/api/index.php but if this is business related it may be worth it.